# MySQL SUM only 1 field and

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table structure

```
--ID-- --Date-- --Value--
  1    2013-1-2     23
  2    2013-1-2     11
  3    2013-1-3     8
  4    2013-1-3     7
```

As you can see the dates can overlap and I want to output every different date with a summation of the values attributed. So for this it would be.

```
--Date--   --Total-- 
2013-1-2      34 
2013-1-3      15
```

Is this even possible with a query or will I have to do some seperate summation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Date, sum(Value) as Total
FROM Table
GROUP BY Date
```